# Extract first "extension" tag in nested xml using pyspark

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark version=3.0with python

I am using pyspark and want to read a XML. There are multiple extension tags and I need only the first tag. Extension is of type array. IF I explode I am getting multiple rows with nulls. I need only below tags

```
<extension>
<docClass>USCOURTS</docClass>
<accessId>USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207</accessId>
<courtType>Bankruptcy</courtType>
<courtCode>txsb</courtCode>
<courtCircuit>5th</courtCircuit>
<courtState>Texas</courtState>
<courtSortOrder>3483</courtSortOrder>
<caseNumber>2:05-bk-21207</caseNumber>
<caseOffice>Corpus Christi</caseOffice>
```

and

```
<relatedItem type="constituent" ID="id-USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207-1" xlink:href="https://www.govinfo.gov/metadata/granule/USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207/USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207-1/mods.xml">
<titleInfo>
<title>ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants</title>
<subTitle>Memorandum Opinion And Order of Bankruptcy Judge On Motion For Summary Judgment Regarding Proof Of Claim Number 9464 Filed By Jerome Davis Signed on 8/19/2009. Proof of Claim Number 9464 is hereby DISALLOWED in its entirety. (Related document(s):7542 Objection to Claim, 8142 Generic Motion) (gjon)</subTitle>
<partNumber>1</partNumber>
</titleInfo>
```

Pyspark code:

```
df = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag", "mods").load("/Users/a/Desktop/USCOURTS-akb-3_15-ap-90018-0.xml")
first_extension = df.select(explode("extension").alias("first_extension"))

first_extension.show(2,False)
```

Complete XML code:

```
https://www.govinfo.gov/metadata/granule/USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207/USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207-10/mods.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there exist multiple extensions, so filter it with some condition, explode related columns and select distincts.

```
df = spark.read.format('xml').option('rowTag', 'mods').load('mods.xml')

df.select('extension', 'relatedItem') \
  .withColumn('extension', f.explode('extension')) \
  .filter('extension.accessId is not null') \
  .withColumn('relatedItem', f.explode('relatedItem')) \
  .select(
    'extension.docClass',
    'extension.accessId',
    'extension.courtType',
    'extension.courtCode',
    'extension.courtCircuit',
    'extension.courtState',
    'extension.courtSortOrder',
    'extension.caseNumber',
    'extension.caseOffice',
    'relatedItem.titleInfo.*'
  ) \
  .distinct() \
  .orderBy('partNumber') \
  .show(100, truncate=False)

+--------+---------------------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|docClass|accessId                   |courtType |courtCode|courtCircuit|courtState|courtSortOrder|caseNumber   |caseOffice    |partNumber|subTitle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |title                                                  |
+--------+---------------------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|0         |Memorandum Opinion And Order of Bankruptcy Judge Richard Schmidt On Motion To File Proofs Of Claim Out Of Time Signed on 10/3/2008 (gluc, )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|1         |Memorandum Opinion And Order of Bankruptcy Judge On Motion For Summary Judgment Regarding Proof Of Claim Number 9464 Filed By Jerome Davis Signed on 8/19/2009. Proof of Claim Number 9464 is hereby DISALLOWED in its entirety. (Related document(s):7542 Objection to Claim, 8142 Generic Motion) (gjon)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|2         |Certified copy of Memorandum Opinion, Order of Confirmation, and Injunction entered. The Court adopts the findings of fact and conclusion of Law subject to any rejections or revisions noted in this opinion. This Court agrees that the Parent's Plan is both feasible and confirmable. It offers the creditors full payment and is more likely to close than the Debtor's Plan. While this court does not minimize the damage that a strike could do should one occur, the Court has a record which supports the findings that a strike is unlikely, and it hopes that reason will prevail and that both sides will decide that mining cooper, while the price remains high, makes money for equity holders and pays good wages for both labor and management. Finally, this Court finds the Original Report and Recommendation not only accurately describes the requirements placed upon it by the Bankruptcy Code, but also finds that the Bankruptcy Court complied with those requirements signed by District Court Judge Andrew S. Hanen in Civil Case No. 2:09-cv-177 on 11/13/2009 (Related document(s):11884 Order Approving Disclosure Statement, 12040 Report and Recommendation) (Attachments: 1 Continuation of Order2 Continuation of Order3 Continuation of Order) (gjon)|ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|3         |Memorandum Opinion and Order on Application of Majority Bondholders Under 11 USC Sections 503(B)(3)(D) and (B)(4) for Payment of Fees and Reimbursement of Expenses for Substantial Contribution Signed on 9/28/2010 (Related document(s):13897 Application for Administrative Expenses) (bcor)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|4         |Memorandum Opinion on Application of The United States and The States of Texas, Montana and Washington Under 11 USC Sections 503(B)(3)(D) and (B)(4) for Payment of Fees and Reimbursement of Expenses for Substantial Contrinution Signed on 9/29/2010 (Related document(s):13872 Application for Administrative Expenses, 13893 Application for Administrative Expenses, 13912 Application for Administrative Expenses, 13916 Application for Administrative Expenses) (bcor)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|5         |Memorandum Opinion And Order On Fee Application And Fee Enhancement Motion Of Barclays Capital Inc of Bankruptcy Judge Signed on 12/2/2010 (Related document(s):13389 Generic Application, 13408 Generic Application, 13850 Application for Compensation) (gcha)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|6         |Memorandum Opinion on Final Fee Application of Baker Botts L.L.P. Signed on 7/20/2011 (Related document(s):13915 Application for Compensation) (Attachments: 1 continuation2 continuation) (vrio)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|7         |Memorandum Opinion on Final Fee Application of Jordan, Hyden, Womble, Culbreth & Holzer, P.C. Signed on 7/20/2011 (Related document(s):13917 Application for Compensation) (vrio)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|8         |Memorandum Opinion with Respect to: (1) Final Application of Oppenheimer, Blend, Harrison & Tate, Inc. (2) Final Application of Robert C. Pate (3) Joint Application of Robert C. Pate and Oppenheimer, Blend, Harrison & Tate, Inc. (4) All Supplements Thereto. Signed on 7/20/2011 (Related document(s):13883 Application for Compensation, 13886 Application for Compensation) (Attachments: 1 continuation) (vrio)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|9         |Memorandum Opinion on Final Application of Stutzman, Bromberg, Esserman & Plifka, a Professional Corporation, for Approval of Attorneys' Fees and Expenses Incurred as Counsel for the Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants for the Period from April 11, 2005 Through January 31, 2010, as Amended and Supplemented. Signed on 7/20/2011 (Related document(s):13881 Application for Compensation) (vrio)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
|USCOURTS|USCOURTS-txsb-2_05-bk-21207|Bankruptcy|txsb     |5th         |Texas     |3483          |2:05-bk-21207|Corpus Christi|10        |Memorandum Opinion And Order On State Of Missouri's Motion For Summary Judgment In The Contested Matter Of Debtor's Motion To Withhold Signed on 11/13/2013 (Related document(s):16420 Motion for Approval) (gcha)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |ASARCO LLC and Official Committee of Asbestos Claimants|
+--------+---------------------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```